# If we use red or green light looking though slit, how will be blur of horizontal and vertical lines?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

When we look through a very narrow slit, the image is blurred. We assume that the aperture is horizontal and we observe the image in red light. We are looking at an image consisting of horizontal and vertical lines. Which lines are more blurred? What will happen when we use green light?

Comment: If you put a narrow slit in front of your eye, you get a nice clean image.  Perhaps you mean that the self-diffraction image downstream has "blurring" ?  In addition, I suspect you mean "object contains vertical and horizontal bars," not "lines" . Lines have zero width.

Comment: Yes, I meant bars. How should I do this exercise?